# Accessing non-zero elements in specific row of matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the indices of the positions of non-zero elements in a sparse matrix in python in the form

```
(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 0, 0], dtype=int32), array([2, 1, 3]))
```

or in the matrix form

```
[[0 2]
 [1 0]
 [2 0]]
```

I want to use this (or some  other method if there is one) to carry out row-by-row operations with only the corresponding non-zero elements of other matrices, like so:

```
for r in range(rows):
    A[r,:] = np.dot(B[r,:],C.T)
```

Basically I need a way to specify the row and only choose the elements from that row that correspond to the non-zero elements from the matrix B.

The part I can't get my head around is due to the fact that there can be a varying number of entries for each row/column.

Comment: How does using just the nonzero elements change the final answer?

Comment: You've set `scipy` and `sparse-matrix` tags.  Does that mean you intend to use `scipy.sparse` matrices?  They can do matrix multiplication (in compiled code).

Comment: the problem is that the matrix B is sparse and huge, and subsequently A and C are going to be large and so for efficiency I only want to complete the multiplication with the non-zero elements. There are far more zero elements than non-zero. I think the solution probably involves scipy.sparse but am not sure and am open to ideas!

Comment: `np.nonzero` gives you the indexes of the nonzero elements.  But even when you know the indexes of those elements, indexing them in `A` and `B` will hurt efficiency more than multiplying the zero elements.

Comment: So I'm comparing the implementation of this to the same equation in matlab where you can have a matrix of existing values and can do something like:       A(r, existing(r,:)) = B(r, existing(r,:))*C'

Comment: I was hoping to implement something similar in python, so is leaving the zero elements in probably going to be faster than trying to replicate the matlab version?

Comment: Does that kind of indexing actualy improve speed in MATLAB?  It might if the density is .01 or less.  But years ago I used MATLAB sparse matrices for finite element calculations.  But sparse was more of a memory saver than a speed tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you can use boolean array indices in python so the following does what I wanted to achieve:

```
for r in range(rows):
    A[r,B[r,:]!=0] = np.dot(B[r , B[r,:]!=0], C[: , B[r,:]!=0].T)
```

looks kind of complicated but it gets the right elements for the calculation. The only problem is when the dimension of B is larger than what it's indexing into which throws an index out of bounds error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little puzzled as to what that first tuple represents.  Is it the indexes and values of a sparse array? e.g.

```
In [4]: arrays=(np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int), np.array([2, 0, 0], dtype=int), np.array([2, 1, 3], dtype=float))
...
In [6]: from scipy import sparse
In [7]: M=sparse.csr_matrix((arrays[2],(arrays[0],arrays[1])))
In [8]: M
Out[8]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [9]: M.A
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  0.]])

In [10]: print(M)
  (0, 2)    2.0
  (1, 0)    1.0
  (2, 0)    3.0
```

Matrix multiplication is defined for such an array:

```
In [12]: M*M.T
Out[12]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [13]: (M*M.T).A
Out[13]: 
array([[ 4.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  9.]])
In [14]: M.A.dot(M.A.T)  # dense equivalent
Out[14]: 
array([[ 4.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  9.]])
```

I could implement a row by row multiplication with this array:

```
In [21]: A=M.A      # dense array
In [22]: for r in range(3):
    print(np.dot(A[r,:],A[r,:]))
4.0
1.0
9.0
# actually this is just the diagonal

In [23]: for r in range(3):   # or with the nonzero elements
    I=np.nonzero(A[r,:])
    dot = np.dot(A[r,I[0]],A[r,I[0]])
    print(dot)
4.0
1.0
9.0
```

for what it's worth, `nonzero` returns the array I copied from your post at the start:

```
In [24]: np.nonzero(A)
Out[24]: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
In [25]: A[np.nonzero(A)]
Out[25]: array([ 2.,  1.,  3.])
```

The sparse matrix also has a `nonzero` method:

```
In [26]: M.nonzero()
Out[26]: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

I feel like I'm floundering around, trying to make sense of the question and the example.